# How to work on a programming project remotely

Tags: software-development

I have several workers working for me remotely. We contact via Gmail chat. The problem is how can we all work on the project without having to send it via email and sending it back.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a project management framework are you using? Mentioning this may help to build more constructive answers.

Comment: What do you mean by "it"? The entire project? Are you looking for a source control solution, or something to facilitate communication? Are you using a Scrum framework? Kanban? Nothing? Please provide some more context.

Comment: As currently written, your question is really more about distributed programming than it is about project management. Please reframe your question if you can; if not, you might have better luck asking about distrubuted programming or distributed version control systems (DVCS) on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I considered closing this question, but since it got answers and no close votes, I decided to ask a [meta question instead about why this is on-topic for a site for project managers](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/459/why-did-no-one-vote-to-close-this-question-about-working-on-a-codebase-remotely). If you can flag or vote to close, please weight in as your insight is valuable! :)

Comment: Ewen, I downvoted because I considered that, to be a useful question in our community, it needs more environment details. For instance, how things are being conducted, shared, stored and aligned. 'Send it by mail' is a void explanation, IMO. On the other hand, the question itself is likely to be quite valuable, once polished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend to use a collaboration service like [hipchat](https://www.hipchat.com/) or [campfire](http://campfirenow.com/).

I was working in a project where we used hipchat and it was really great. All the discussions where saved, the version control system (git) and the continuous integration system (jenkins) posted messages to the chat so that we knew what is happening and who is doing what.

[Basecamp](http://basecamp.com/) is another great tool which was designed for the work you just described in your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an internal server that everyone has access to, you can set up an Apache/[Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) or [git](http://gitstack.com/) server.  If not then you can get an account on github.  They are pretty cheap.  There are other hosted source code management (SCM) sites out there as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working on a .NET project, one option is to use Team Foundation Server on a local server, or Team Foundation Server in the Cloud.

This will allow you to share and contribute to a common codebase, with a system in place to manage conflicts.

This is not much different than an office where multiple developers will check in code without discussing it first.